# Getting sensible info from CLR-to-SEH exceptions in a mixed mode C++ project

Tags: .net, c++, exception, c++-cli

Mixed mode C++ project. Native code is calling managed code. Managed code might throw an exception. I can catch said exception in native mode using a vectored exception handler; I can see its `PEXCEPTION_POINTERS`. The telling code 0xE0434F4D, meaning it's a CLR exception, is there.

Question: is there any way to get any sensible information (exception class, message, stack trace etc.) from the attendant data? There's one parameter in the `ExceptionInformation`, and it looks like a pointer to something...

Comment: No, that's too late.  All you got is the exception code.  You might get something in ExceptionInformation if the original managed exception was caused by a processor fault.  Like NullReference or AccessViolation.  This won't be helpful since you don't know the original SEH exception anymore.  Using COM give you a better mouse trap, the CLR implements IErrorInfo.  But the managed code you're trying to run is probably not [ComVisible].  Calling the code through a managed stub that catches Exception might be a better angle.

Comment: @HansPassant, no offence - but that's not a comment, it's an answer.  Make it so!

Comment: Everybody likes happy answers.  That's not a happy answer.

Comment: "managed stub that catches Exception" - elaborate, please. Is there a way to install a single stub that somehow catches all managed-to-native transitions? I have several entry points into managed code, and I don't want to place a try{}catch(){throw} around each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's too late. All you got is the exception code. You might get something in ExceptionInformation if the original managed exception was caused by a processor fault. Like NullReference or AccessViolation. This won't be helpful since you don't know the original SEH exception anymore. Using COM give you a better mouse trap, the CLR implements IErrorInfo. But the managed code you're trying to run is probably not [ComVisible]. Calling the code through a managed stub that catches Exception might be a better angle.

Comment: I'm posting this as answer in spirit of following blog post
http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/09/15.html

Answer (score 1):

There is similar answer to this question here:
[Catching a CLR exception through unmanaged code](http://www.dotnet247.com/247reference/msgs/71/357596.aspx)

This was resolved in the following manner:

```
#import <mscorlib.tlb> raw_interfaces_only no_smart_pointers named_guids no_implementation

ATL::CComPtr< IErrorInfo > spErrorInfo;
ATL::CComPtr< mscorlib::_Exception > spCLRException;
ATL::CComPtr< mscorlib::_Exception > spCLRInnerException;

ATL::CComBSTR bstrCLRStackTrace;
ATL::CComBSTR bstrCLRMessage;

GetErrorInfo(0, &spErrorInfo)
spErrorInfo.QueryInterface(&spCLRException)
spCLRException->get_InnerException(&spCLRInnerException)
spCLRInnerException->get_StackTrace(&bstrCLRStackTrace)
spCLRInnerException->get_Message(&bstrCLRMessage)
```